# What this typedef is trying to do and How to use?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-definition

1. `struct boolean_struct { int member; }
   typedef int boolean_struct::* boolean_type;`
2. `typedef char(&yes)[1];`

Please explain what these typedef are doing. I really want to understand them.

Comment: These are covered in any reasonably [good text book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). It will be helpful for your in the long run to work through a text book. Getting answers to these specific questions won't help you in the long run if you don't get a solid understanding of all the fundamental aspects of the language.

Comment: Did you do any research?

Comment: Hint:  look up member function pointer syntax and array syntax.

Answer (score -4):

They create alias for some text for example:

`typedef int kappa;
kappa a; // the type of a is int`

Better than `typedef` is `using` alias because it's more readable, and their meaning is the same.

`using kappa = int;
kappa a; // the type of a is int`

Comment: Those are some moderately difficult `typedef`s, and this answer only addresses trivial `typedef`s.